# ReactNative with code-push AOS build [Error : Duplicate resources]

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

I'm applying CodePush to React Native
I'm getting a build error on the Android side when finalizing the application.
I would appreciate it if you could take a look

**Error Message**

```
> Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
ERROR:[string/CodePushDeploymentKey] /Users/up/Desktop/project/coinpickle-app/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/CodePushDeploymentKey] /Users/up/Desktop/project/coinpickle-app/android/app/build/generated/res/resValues/release/values/gradleResValues.xml: Resource and asset merger: Duplicate resources
```

**Probable Cause**
I have code overlap in my CodePush setup

**Mycode**

```
1. strings.xml

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">XXXXXX</string>
    <string moduleConfig="true" name="CodePushDeploymentKey">XXXXXX</string> // Duplicate code here 
</resources>

2. gradleResValues.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY -->

    <!-- Value from build type: debug -->
    <string name="CODE_PUSH_APK_BUILD_TIME" translatable="false">"1697169479092"</string>
    <!-- Value from build type: debug -->
    <string name="CodePushDeploymentKey" translatable="false"></string> // Duplicate code here 
    <!-- Value from default config. -->
    <integer name="react_native_dev_server_port">8081</integer>
    <!-- Value from default config. -->
    <integer name="react_native_inspector_proxy_port">8081</integer>

</resources>
```

```
app/build.gradle

 buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_DEBUG
        }
        releaseStaging {
            initWith release
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_STAGING
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_PRODUCTION
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
```

**Tried**

1. Modify the configuration file
2. Delete duplicate code from sgrings.xml (another error occurs when deleting: R does not exit)
3. rebuild and build clean all

**Desired**
Why duplicate code happens and how to fix it safely

I need help from experts and those who have encountered the error, please. ㅠ-ㅠ

Answer (score 0):

Its happen due to your java version. you can downgrade to java 11. it works for me

Comment: I fixed it now, but it was a package conflict, thanks for the reply!